# How can i make a string that only accepts numbers and the character "." in c?

Tags: c, string, char

im trying to make a program in c that detects if a number is an integrer or a float, and if it is a float counts the number of decimal places.

But im having an issue here, when i insert a float number, because of the "." the program says it is a "word" and not a number since i made it accept only numbers and i get stuck in the while loop.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BASE 10

main()
{
    int length, number;
    char str[10];
    char ch = '.';
    char *ret;
    char *endptr;

    do{
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

     number = strtol(str, &endptr, BASE);

    }while (*endptr != '\0' || endptr == str);

   ret = strchr(str, ch);

    if(ret > 0){

    length = strlen(ret);
    printf("decimal places: %d\n", length - 1);
    }
    else {

         printf("the number is integrer\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you try strtod ? If you only want to test for numbers and point you should do strtol once than test end of string or ´.’ , and if ‘.’, test chars followings ‘.’ with strtol.

Comment: Note: Avoid overrun  problems `char str[10]; ...    scanf("%s", str);` --> `char str[80]; ...    scanf("%79s", str);`

Comment: seixo paulo, "and if it is a float counts the number of decimal places.": with input like "123.456e2", is that 1 or 3 decimal places? Is `"123.456e3"` an integer?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  having letters is what im trying to avoid, because the program would count "123.456e2" as 5 decimal places and we all know that's wrong.

Comment: @PtitXav that sounds like a good ideia, but how could i do that? sorry im not visualising how i could do that

Comment: The `e` in `"123.456e2"` introduces exponential notation.  That string, converted to a `double` would the same value as  `"12345.6"`.  "we all know that's wrong" --> C does not see that as wrong.

Comment: yeah C does not, but we do, that is what i was trying to explain

Answer (score 0):

Using `strtol` is only meaningful once you know that the input is an integer. If you know that the input is a floating-point number, then you can use `strtod` instead. There is no function that can handle both types, unless you want to handle integers as floating-point numbers.

In order to determine whether the input is an integer, floating-point or invalid input, it would probably be best to examine the input string yourself, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[100];

retry_input:

    //prompt user for input
    printf( "Enter number: " );

    //read one line of input
    if ( fgets( str, sizeof str, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //if newline character exists, remove it
    str[strcspn(str,"\n")] = '\0';

    //this variable keeps track of the number of digits encountered
    int num_digits = 0;

    //this variable specifies whether we have encountered a decimal point yet
    bool found_decimal_point = false;

    //inspect the string one character at a time
    for ( char *p = str; *p!='\0'; p++ )
    {
        if ( *p == '.' )
        {
            if ( found_decimal_point )
            {
                printf( "encountered multiple decimal points!\n" );
                goto retry_input;
            }

            found_decimal_point = true;
        }
        else if ( isdigit( (unsigned char)*p ) )
        {
            num_digits++;
        }
        else if ( *p != '+' && *p != '-' )
        {
            printf( "encountered unexpected character in input!\n" );
            goto retry_input;
        }
        else if ( p - str != 0 )
        {
            printf(
                "sign characters (+/-) are only permitted at the start "
                "of the string!\n"
            );
            goto retry_input;
        }
    }

    if ( found_decimal_point )
    {
        //input is floating-point

        printf( "The input is float and has %d digits.\n", num_digits );
    }
    else
    {
        //input is integer

        printf( "The input is integer and has %d digits.\n", num_digits );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that this program will also count the number of digits encountered, and print the total number at the end of the program. Since you stated in the question that you wanted to count the "number of decimal places", this may be what you want.

Also note that this program won't accept floating point numbers in exponential notation.